# Work-around for Error: Float(s) lost

Tags: pdf

=======================================================

## -> Update <-

After a half day trial and error, it's safe to say that this is caused by the

"famous" error `Error: Float(s) lost`.

I have been reading on this site, but it seems that the *only* way was to take it out of the `mini-figure` thing. No other useful work around at the moment.

## =======================================================

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}% for pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Example and Solution

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{example}{+O{}}{%
        enhanced, 
        breakable,
        coltitle=black, 
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={Example~\thetcbcounter:},
        attach title to upper=\quad,
        before lower={\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
        %lowerbox=invisible,
        bicolor,
        colback=black!5!white,
        colbacklower=black!3!white,
        #1}
%\tcbset{student/.style={lowerbox=invisible}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\pdfoptionpdfminorversion 6

\begin{document}


\begin{example}

Figure~\ref{fig:conti_pdf_cdf} gives the probability density function $f(x)$ and its cumulative function $F(x)$.
\begin{figure}[!hp]
    \centering
    \subfigure[$f(x)$]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{15-1.pdf}}  %1.5 version
    \\[2ex]
    \subfigure[$F(x)$]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{15-2.pdf}}
    \caption{Illustration of $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ for a (continuous) piecewise function}
    \label{fig:conti_pdf_cdf}
\end{figure}


\tcblower

Figure~\ref{fig:conti_pdf_cdf} gives the probability density function $f(x)$ and its cumulative function $F(x)$.
\begin{figure}[!hp]
    \centering
    \subfigure[$f(x)$]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{14-1.pdf}} %1.4 version
    \\[2ex]
    \subfigure[$F(x)$]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{14-2.pdf}}
    \caption{Illustration of $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ for a (continuous) piecewise function}
    \label{fig:conti_pdf_cdf}
\end{figure}



\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{chap3_eg1.pdf} % 1.4 version
\end{center}

\end{example}



\end{document}
```

If I compile it without the `example` environment, it works fine.

If I then add the `example` environment, it does not compile (no graph for the 1.4 or 1.5 version PDF). Ignoring the warning, only the `{chap3_eg1.pdf}` shows in the final PDF.

Would there be any specific things (in the PDF) that is causing latex not to compile the PDF? Both 1.4 and 1.5 version is the `same` file. I used Acrobat to convert between versions.

So any solution?

=======================================================

## OLD post

Sorry about the messy title. I will try to make it simple.

In the first instance, I was trying to implement implement [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434055/hide-show-solution-for-problems/434156?noredirect=1#comment1090686_434156) (see comments). So I used

```
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{exercise}{+O{}}{%
    enhanced, breakable,
    coltitle=black, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={Exercise~\thetcbcounter:},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    before lower={\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
    #1}
```

I got an error.

```
! pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file.
```

No PDF file was produced. It worked fine after I did

```
% \pdfoptionpdfminorversion 6
```

With a different `.tex` file, I got this error and I found the lost PDFs (version 1.5)

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

They were coded using

```
\begin{figure}[!hp]
    \centering
    \subfigure[$f(x)$]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{chap3_eg3_den.pdf}}
    \\[2ex]
    \subfigure[$F(x)$]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{chap3_eg3_cum.pdf}}
    \caption{Illustration of $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ for a (continuous) piecewise function}
    \label{fig:conti_pdf_cdf}
\end{figure}
```

Did some research, says something to do with figures in figures or `\marginpar`. But looking at my code, I don't think it is this case here.

I have other PDF (also 1.5) that works fine.

I guess my question really is - What's causing it?

The `packages`?
The `Floats` (subfigure)? Or
The `PDFVersion` thing??

Comment: Invest 15 minutes in a better problem description. One with a complete example demonstrating the (first) error, log-file and a description of your tex system. As it is the question is a mess.

Comment: Use `example-image` instead of the pdfs and see if you still get an error?

Comment: @Troy (same) still error, tried with `example-image`. I have even tried using `.jpg`. I think there is just something clashing with `example` environment was introduced. But weirdly, if I take out the whole environment, it compiles fine, even mixed versions of PDFs.

Comment: My point is that: then it's not an issue with the pdf versions? Get rid of the floating (figure) environments in the example environment. Just use includegraphics and see if it compiles.

Comment: @Troy Yes, I think it's safe to say that this problem is caused by the `example` environment. I have been reading on this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79185/how-to-find-the-lost-text-part-when-having-floats-lost-error but was not able to find any useful workarounds. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not difficult to define a nonfloating version of `figure`.

In the code I changed `subfigure` (deprecated for about 15 years) to `subfig` and, consequently, `\subfigure` to `\subfloat`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}% for pictures

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Example and Solution

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{example}{+O{}}{%
        enhanced, 
        breakable,
        coltitle=black, 
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={Example~\thetcbcounter:},
        attach title to upper=\quad,
        before lower={\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
        %lowerbox=invisible,
        bicolor,
        colback=black!5!white,
        colbacklower=black!3!white,
        #1}
%\tcbset{student/.style={lowerbox=invisible}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fixedfigure}
 {\def\@captype{figure}\center}
 {\endcenter}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\pdfoptionpdfminorversion 6

\begin{document}

\begin{example}

Figure~\ref{fig:conti_pdf_cdf} gives the probability density function $f(x)$ and its cumulative function $F(x)$.
\begin{fixedfigure}
    \subfloat[$f(x)$]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}\qquad
    \subfloat[$F(x)$]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
    \caption{Illustration of $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ for a (continuous) piecewise function}
    \label{fig:conti_pdf_cdf}
\end{fixedfigure}


\tcblower

Figure~\ref{fig:conti_pdf_cdf-B} gives the probability density function $f(x)$ and its cumulative function $F(x)$.
\begin{fixedfigure}
    \subfloat[$f(x)$]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}\qquad
    \subfloat[$F(x)$]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
    \caption{Illustration of $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ for a (continuous) piecewise function}
    \label{fig:conti_pdf_cdf-B}
\end{fixedfigure}



\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image} % 1.4 version
\end{center}

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, as always from egreg! To avoid renaming every instance of `figure`, I went for the radical: ``\renewenvironment{figure}``  (it's easy to regex `figure` to `fixedfigure`, but my figures are imported by beamer and other classes I use, so it was more convenient to keep the word `figure`)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have large chapters some with tens of figures. This error appeared when I migrated to a different latex template (from memoir to kaobook) however the migration wasn't necessarily the cause of the problem, the problem happened to be latent in the memoir template. Here's a sanitized extract of the code:

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption[Three layers of an app]{Three layers of an app \sidenote{Image credit: First published somewhere else~\cite{harty_aymer_playbook_2016}}.}
\label{fig:3-layers}
\end{figure*}
```

The `\sidenote{...}` for kaobook or `\footnote{...}` for memoir led to the Float(s) lost message later in the chapter. One of the images was indeed not displayed in the generated PDF.

I used `\clearpage` before each `\section{...}` to help me track down where the problem was being triggered. That led me to this figure.

The workaround was to remove the sidenote/footnote command as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption[Three layers of an app]{Three layers of an app {Image credit: First published somewhere else~\cite{harty_aymer_playbook_2016}}.}
\label{fig:3-layers}
\end{figure*}
```

Note: I temporarily left the `{}` around the text as that was quick and easy to do to test my theory. These were removed once I'd seen the error had been addressed. I hope this may help others who follow.