# How to spare selected theorems from thmbox styles?

Tags: thmbox

I'm using the thmbox package. I'm trying to find a way to make some of my theorems have the thmbox look, while having some other having the traditional theorems look.

My problem is that the different thmbox styles do not seem to include an "empty" style (to my knowledge, there's only the `[S]`, `[M]` and `[L]` styles), and applying the `\usepackage[nothm]{thmbox}` makes *all* the theorems have the traditional theorem look.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you simply define the "empty" style using the regular ``\newtheorem`` command from ``amsthm``?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The \theoremstyle option of asmthm only change the header in terms of font ans space. It doesn't seem to affect the use of thmbox style

Comment: It will indeed not affect ``thmbox`` if you define a theorem using ``\newtheorem``. Just to be sure that I understand your question correctly, you want to have some theorems displayed in a ``thmbox`` style, and others in an "empty" style, like the one obtained by default using ``\newtheorem`` with ``amsthm``?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I would be looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the `amsthm` package before the `thmbox` package, and define a command `\newemptytheorem` from `\newtheorem` before `\newtheorem` gets redefined by `thmbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\newemptytheorem\newtheorem
\usepackage{thmbox}

\newemptytheorem{emptythm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{boxedthm}[emptythm]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{emptythm}
A theorem in an "empty" style.
\end{emptythm}

\begin{boxedthm}
A theorem in a \textnormal{\texttt{thmbox}} style.
\end{boxedthm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you!